# What pane is most fit?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I need to build software in JavaFX so I watched some tutorials to have some background.

Anyway, I have no idea what kind of pane I should use, Should I use VBox and inside HBox for any components "line"?

The Canvas area is for drag and drop tables, canvas object is fit?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a Ribbon control in JavaFX like your screen, it is easier to implement a RibbonPane control extends TabPane and change the CSS of the control.

I have implemented a RibbonPane control for my [customersfx demo application](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/) in JavaFX 8. You can check the controls in the application:

1. [RibbonPane](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/control/RibbonPane.java) extends TabPane
2. [RibbonTab](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/control/RibbonTab.java) extends Tab
3. [RibbonGroup](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/control/RibbonGroup.java) extends HBox
4. [RibbonCommand](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/control/RibbonCommand.java) extends Button
5. [AppView](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/view/AppView.java) has the RibbonPane with tabs and actions.

Comment: Hi friend, as you already understood , i'm kind of new in javaFX businesses.
How do i  import your components to my project?
I barley know how to do that with jar files, but no clue with java file and resources and so on..

Comment: You can download all source code and add packages/controls to your project. Unfortunately I don't have my controls in maven repositories.